# How to reference a folder in the previous directory in a batch file?

Tags: ffmpeg, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

I have the following script for converting videos with FFmpeg:

```
for %%a in ("*.mp4*") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -y -c:v prores_ks -profile:v proxy -pix_fmt yuv422p10le -vendor ap10 -bits_per_mb 8000  -vf "scale=1920:1080" -c:a pcm_s16le -ar 48K "..\%%~na.mov"
pause
```

As you can see, the output path of the file is the folder before the source file folder.

The issue is that I want the output of the file to be in a folder that is in the previous directory of the source file, but I've been racking my brains for hours and I couldn't make it work.

To be a little clearer, I would like the output of the file to look something like this:

```
..\01. Proxy\%%~na.mov
```

How should I write the code?